# How to resolve API data being fetched using Vue and Vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

im having some problems regarding vue (vue2) when i try fetching data from an api and it returns undefined whenever i try to accesss the data from the component, but the data is visible whenever i console it.  im using some vuex as my state management library. anyone know what the issue might be?

actions.js (store)

```
import axios from '@/axios';
import { getMessageFromError } from '../utils/functions';

export default {

    async getLabels({ commit }) {
    try {
      const api_res = await fetch('http://localhost:1337/api/home-page', {});
      const res = await api_res.json()
      console.log(api_res)
      
      commit('SET_STATE', {
        action: 'loading',
        data: false,
      });
      commit('SET_STATE', {
        action: 'labelsData',
        data: res.data?.attributes,
      });
    } catch (error) {
      commit('SET_STATE', {
        action: 'loading',
        data: false,
      });
      const { message } = getMessageFromError(error);
      return Promise.reject({
        message,
      });
      // console.log(error)
    }
  },
};
```

Home.vue

```
<template>

  <div>
     <!-- For Warrning -->
    <div v-if="checkRolesByIds([ADMIN])">
      <div v-if="stripeInfo.stripe_secret_key == null && stripeInfo.stripe_public_key == null">
      <vs-alert color="warning" title="Profile incomplete" active="true"> First you need to complete your profile. Please provide your stripe account details from your profile menu. </vs-alert>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- End -->
    <vs-row v-if="checkRolesByIds([ADMIN])" class="mt-8">
      <vs-col class="vx-col w-full md:w-1/6 px-4">
        <vs-card actionable class="cardx bg-green-500">
          <div slot="header" class="mt-2 flex items-center justify-between">
            <div>
              <feather-icon icon="DollarSignIcon" class="p-3 inline-flex rounded-full text-success mb-2" :style="{ background: `rgba(var(--vs-success),.15)` }" />
              <span v-if="labelsData" class="block font-semibold">{{ labelsData }}: {{ dashboardData.donationsCounts || 0 }} </span>
              <span v-else class="block font-semibold">hi: {{ dashboardData.donationsCounts || 0 }} </span>
            </div>
            <h3></h3>
          </div>
          <p class="text-center mt-2" @click="$router.push({ name: 'donations-list' }).catch(() => {})">View</p>
        </vs-card>
      </vs-col>
    </vs-row>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapActions, mapState, mapGetters } from 'vuex'
import { dateMixins } from '@/mixins/dateMixins.js'
import { ADMIN, SYSTEM_ADMIN } from '@/utils/roles'

export default {
  name: 'EventList',
  // Form Data
  data() {
    return {
      ADMIN,
      SYSTEM_ADMIN,
      length: 10,
      page: 1
    }
  },
  mixins: [dateMixins],
  computed: {
    ...mapState('auth', ['labelsData']),
    ...mapGetters('auth', ['checkRolesByIds'])
  },
  /* API Calling Function */
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('auth', { getLabels: 'getLabels' }),
    getData() {
      this.getLabels()
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getData()
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: `console.log(api_res)` logs the response (not the data) .... try `console.log(res)` ... does it have a `data` property? why do you `import axios` but use `fetch`? is that why you think the result (`res`) would automatically have a `data` property, because `axios` is not `fetch`?

Comment: Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , there's no SET_STATE and no data listed